# Will the font size change depending on what heading I use (h1,h2,h3) if I use css to change it to a certain font size

Tags: html, css

If I do:

```
<h1> This is text</h1>
<h2> This is also text</h2>
```

and also use css to change the font size like this:

```
.h1 {
    font-size: 30px
}
.h2{
    font-size: 30px
}
```

Will both the text be the same size or will it change because I used different headings. If it does change, then how much pixels will both the text actually be?

Comment: both will be on same size

Comment: all you have to do is to test and see

Comment: @editor: please don't correct the wrong code ... `h1` is different from `.h1` and this may be the issue!

Comment: why not create a snippet and run the code - you will see what it does

Comment: Come on, you can test this yourself faster then writing this question.

Comment: Because you are using `px` font size yes they will be the same size if you were using something `em` it could inherit its size from other elements on the page making them different

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
}
h2{
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1> This is text</h1>
<h2> This is also text</h2>
```

no it does not depend on it
just press on "Run code snippet" and you'll see.

with kind regards: speschel

Answer (score -1):

They will be the same size, as you can see in this example:

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-size: 50px;

  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

h1 {
  color: red;
}

h2 {
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is text</h1>
<h2>This is text</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried it on chrome,the result shows if you use CSS to change the font size,they would be the same size and the value was what you set .

Answer (score -1):

If you use different headings, it's for organize your HTML code so if you change the size value of headings, there will be no impact on the size.